What can I do about a drip under my kitchen sink?
For months, there has been a drip from the pipe under the kitchen sink. I have put a jug under to collect the drip from the pipe. It's time to fix it, and I would like your help in identifying steps to fix it. Can you please guide me?


It is most likely at a joint.  Might just need to tighten the leaking joint or just replace the pipes.  Those white pipes are inexpensive and should undo by hand turning only.

Given that it looks from your photo that you have a belly in the pipe+joint, it's a good guess that the joint is not secure.  IDK how the heck that pipe is draining.

That's a lot of couplers/joints in there. Definitely could be simplified, per both of the answers.

The connection to the sink basket seems wonky. If the photo isn't deceiving my eye, the drip would have to come from a higher point.

Make sure you understand how those compression joints work. There's a threaded nut, a nylon gasket, and a threaded pipe hub. They all need to be present and in good condition. The gasket needs to be oriented correctly, with the tapered face away from the nut. Take them apart and look them over. Clean any gunk off the parts. Look for damaged gaskets.

Reassemble and tighten hand-tight plus half a turn. That should be plenty in a no-pressure situation.



image source (YouTube)

how do I measure the size of the pipe incase I want to buy one?

Pipe is described by inside diameter. PVC and ABS will be about +3/8" on the outside. Thin-wall nylon will be about +1/4".

First, you need to figure out where the drip originates.
Assuming that the leak is between the black fitting and the white pipe from the sink, you should do two things. Simplify the system and replace the black fitting with longer pipes. (Less joints mean less potential leaks.) Next, ensure that the horizontal run from under the sink to the p-trap has smooth downward slope. You can probably adjust how the pipe enters the p-trap to make this happen.



At "A" it looks like the washer has been squeezed out from under the nut.
The entirety of "B" is a disaster and unnecessary.  There should be nothing there at all.
"C", the dishwasher connection, is supposed to be vertical.  The reason that little white nub comes out of the white pipe at an angle is that it is supposed to point up and the dishwasher hose is supposed to be above it so it doesn't collect sewage from the sink.

The fix: Completely replace all the pipery.  There is more than one way to do it but here's a nice example.  Dishwasher hose descends at all times towards drain, no unecessary joints in drain, all joints are correctly aligned, and all the pipes and fittings are the same kind (no mixing tubular, PVC, ABS, etc).

